# Timing additions to serial data saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, serial-port

I have written a program to save serial data from an arduino, plotted it, added a timestamp to it and saved the data to a CSV. The serial data is sent every few seconds. However, the timing of the arduino program doesn't line up with the Python program and every so often goes out of phase and I get a timestamp in the wrong column of the CSV file which makes processing the data difficult.

I think the solution is a `for` loop controlled by `range` but cannot quite work out how to do it.

Relevant code is below, the serial data is between 1-32 plots but I have condensed it to 3 here for space reasons however I usually comment out the irrelevant ones hence the desire for a range bound for loop.

```
line=ser.readline()      #ascii
print(line)
seconds = time.time()

line_as_list = line.split(b',')
J = float(line_as_list[0]) 
L = float(line_as_list[1])
M = float(line_as_list[2])
relProb = line_as_list[4] 
relProb_as_list = relProb.split(b'\n')
relProb_float = float(relProb_as_list[0])

# Add x and y to lists
xs.append(seconds)
As.append(J)
bs.append(L)
cs.append(M)


# Limit x and y lists to 20 items
#xs = xs[-20:]
#ys = ys[-20:]

# Draw x and y lists
ax.clear()
ax.plot(xs, As, label="Plot 1")
ax.plot(xs, bs, label="Plot 2")
ax.plot(xs, cs, label="Plot 3")


dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
f = open('Datafile.csv','a')
line=str(line,"utf-8") ## the UTF-8 bit is essential to make it not have b' '
timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")#convert time to string


f.write(timestampStr)#write the time to the file
f.write(",") # seperate the time from the data
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the problem is that the processing time for the loop is too long, and you may not only be missing parts of lines, but entire lines themselves at times. What happens when a serial buffer fills up depends on the hardware and the specific driver used with it (usb-serial driver probably?). It seems like the serial input buffer is filling up, and silently throwing out some data. I imagine that drawing your plots is probably the slowest part of the code because matplotilb uses cpu rendering, and is designed for customization rather than speed. I see two solutions to this problem: speed up your code to the point where it can keep up, or separate the process of drawing the graphs from the process of reading the serial port using threading.

There are probably lots of little things you can do to speed up your code, but one of the biggest is probably to look into matplotlib's [animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) features which are designed to minimize the extra processing necessary to only update the parts of the graph which have changed.

The other option (though the two could actually be combined) is to move the reading of the serial port to a separate thread so the drawing of the graph does not interrupt the flow of data. A quick example base on your code might look like this (some things inferred about your code):

```
import serial
import time
from threading import Thread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

ser = serial.Serial()
xs = []
As = []
bs = []
cs = []

fig, (ax,) = plt.subplots(1,1)
f = open('Datafile.csv','a')

keep_reading = True

def reader_thread():
    while keep_reading:
        #do processing on img
        
        line=ser.readline()      #ascii
        print(line)
        seconds = time.time()
        
        line_as_list = line.split(b',')
        J = float(line_as_list[0]) 
        L = float(line_as_list[1])
        M = float(line_as_list[2])
        relProb = line_as_list[4] 
        relProb_as_list = relProb.split(b'\n')
        relProb_float = float(relProb_as_list[0])
        
        # Add x and y to lists
        xs.append(seconds)
        As.append(J)
        bs.append(L)
        cs.append(M)
        
        
        # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
        #xs = xs[-20:]
        #ys = ys[-20:]
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
        
        line=str(line,"utf-8") ## the UTF-8 bit is essential to make it not have b' '
        timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")#convert time to string
        
        
        f.write(timestampStr)#write the time to the file
        f.write(",") # seperate the time from the data
        f.write(line)

try:
    t = Thread(target=reader_thread)
    t.start()
    while True:
        # Draw x and y lists
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(xs, As, label="Plot 1")
        ax.plot(xs, bs, label="Plot 2")
        ax.plot(xs, cs, label="Plot 3")
        time.sleep(.1) #not strictly necessary
except KeyboardInterrupt: #ctrl-c to quit
    pass
finally:
    keep_reading = False
    t.join()
    ser.close()
    f.close()
```

Comment: The serial data is only sent every 5 seconds and isn't very long, 8 x 6character numbers, the serial buffer is definitely not overflowing.

Comment: @MParks if that's the case, then I don't think the problem is with the code you posted. You may have a faulty serial connection or a bug in your arduino code...